# Trait for conversion of references and owned values to Cow

Tags: rust, traits

I have a function that can handle both owned and borrowed values of some type `Foo` by accepting a `Cow<'_, Foo>`. However, I'd like to make it more convenient by allowing to pass in owned or borrowed `Foo`s directly.

Is it possible to have a conversion trait to `Cow` that's implemented both on a reference type and its owned version?

This is what I tried:

```
trait Convert<'a> : Clone {
    fn into_cow(self) -> Cow<'a, Self>;
}

// Works
impl<'a> Convert<'a> for Foo {
    fn into_cow(self) -> Cow<'a, Self> {
        println!("owned");
        Cow::Owned(self)
    }
}

// Doesn't work
impl<'a> Convert<'a> for &'a Foo {
    fn into_cow(self) -> Cow<'a, Self> {
        println!("borrowed");
        Cow::Borrowed(self)
    }
}
```

The borrowed version says that `Borrowed` expected a `&&'a Foo` but found a `&'a Foo`.

Answer (score 1):

`Self` in the implementation of a trait for `&Foo` is `&Foo`, so `into_cow()` doesn't return the same type in both impls.

One solution would be to change the return type to `Cow<'a, Foo>`, but that of course limits the trait to only work on `Foo`.

A better way is to make the owned type a generic parameter of `Convert` like this:

```
trait Convert<'a, T: Clone> {
    fn into_cow(self) -> Cow<'a, T>;
}

impl<'a, T: Clone> Convert<'a, T> for T {
    fn into_cow(self) -> Cow<'a, T> {
        println!("owned");
        Cow::Owned(self)
    }
}

impl<'a, T: Clone> Convert<'a, T> for &'a T {
    fn into_cow(self) -> Cow<'a, T> {
        println!("borrowed");
        Cow::Borrowed(self)
    }
}

fn take_foo<'a>(foo: impl Convert<'a, Foo>) {
    let cow = foo.into_cow();
}

fn main() {
    take_foo(&Foo{});
    take_foo(Foo{});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you ever make use of the ownership, or always reborrow it? If only reborrowing, is [`std::convert::AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) what you're looking for?

```
fn take_foo(foo: impl AsRef<Foo>) {
    let foo: &Foo = foo.as_ref();
    todo!();
}
```

Comment: No, I make use of the ownership.